Flutter Grid View Stick to Bottom inside a List View
I am trying to create an application for university project using flutter.  My current code is as follows.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mathappcd/constants/widgets_constants.dart';
import 'package:mathappcd/screens/sectionA.dart';
import 'package:mathappcd/screens/sectionB.dart';
import 'package:mathappcd/widgets/app_bar.dart';
import 'package:mathappcd/widgets/square_btn.dart';

extension ContextExtension on BuildContext {
  bool get isSmallScreen => MediaQuery.of(this).size.shortestSide < 500;
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustAppBar(
        title: "App",
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Graph"),
            ),
          ),
          GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(WidgetConstants.sqrBtnPadding),
            mainAxisSpacing: 20,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            crossAxisCount: context.isSmallScreen ? 2 : 4,
            children: const [
              SquareBtn(
                text: "A",
                directTo: SectionA(),
              ),
              SquareBtn(
                text: "B",
                directTo: SectionB(),
              ),
              SquareBtn(
                text: "C",
                directTo: SectionA(),
              ),
              SquareBtn(
                text: "D",
                directTo: SectionB(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

And it gives the result like this.
But I want the grid view to stick to bottom as in this image.
I achived this using a Column and a spacer but then when the screen height isn't enough it gives an error like this. I have tried many other ways but failed to get the exact result I needed. I want it to be responsive and also the whole wcreen to be scrollable when the screen height is lesser than the height of SizedBox (Graph) + Grid View.
Please help! Thanks in advance.

Use your solutions using a column and spacer, but wrap the Column with a SingleChildScollView widget

@MendelG It doesn't seem to work. Error:
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
space in the vertical direction.

ListView is giving the wrong output as items in listview have a standart size. each item will be the same size and can also be manipulated by setting itemExtent parameter.
You can implement your code using a singlechild scrollview (to remove the rendeflex issue if the children are big) and column.
Edited:
extension ContextExtension on BuildContext {
  bool get isSmallScreen => MediaQuery.of(this).size.shortestSide < 500;
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustAppBar(
        title: "App",
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Graph"),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: GridView.count(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(WidgetConstants.sqrBtnPadding),
              mainAxisSpacing: 20,
              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
              crossAxisCount: context.isSmallScreen ? 2 : 4,
              children: const [
                SquareBtn(
                  text: "A",
                  directTo: SectionA(),
                ),
                SquareBtn(
                  text: "B",
                  directTo: SectionB(),
                ),
                SquareBtn(
                  text: "C",
                  directTo: SectionA(),
                ),
                SquareBtn(
                  text: "D",
                  directTo: SectionB(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thank you for the reply, but this doesn't really bring the Gridview to bottom of the screen...

Oh, I misunderstood the opposite will edit and post the answer again.

Finally after with help of ChatGPT and tinkering around I figured out a way.
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Widget getBanner() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: WidgetConstants.bannerHeight,
            minHeight: WidgetConstants.bannerHeight),
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            "Graph or something to show the progress",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getHomeButtons() {
    return Container(
      constraints:
          const BoxConstraints(minHeight: WidgetConstants.homeBtnsHeight),
      child: Center(
        child: GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(WidgetConstants.sqrBtnPadding),
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          crossAxisCount: context.isSmallWidth ? 2 : 4,
          children: const [
            SquareBtn(
              text: "A",
              directTo: SectionA(),
            ),
            SquareBtn(
              text: "B",
              directTo: SectionB(),
            ),
            SquareBtn(
              text: "C",
              directTo: SectionA(),
            ),
            SquareBtn(
              text: "D",
              directTo: SectionB(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustAppBar(
        title: "App",
      ),
      body: context.isSmallheight
          ? ListView(
              children: [
                getBanner(),
                getHomeButtons(),
              ],
            )
          : Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: getBanner()),
                getHomeButtons(),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}

Since ListView and Column seemed work at different situations I just put a condition at the body and called the content from a different function. This gave the exact result I needed.
